# Is there a way to Relabel a detected field value contained that is part of JSON with Loki?

Tags: grafana-loki

I haven't been able to find this in the Loki documentation.

Currently, my logs contain a Label `resource` that has information about the running service.  Ideally, I would like to extract some of these values to make the logs very easy to filter by.

This is what the label value looks like:

```
{"labels":{"configuration_name":"myservicename","location":"region","service_name":"myservicename},"type":""}
```

I'd like to be able to remap the service_name.  I'm using the Helm chart, and setting the values for `scrapeConfigs.relabel_configs` - I have this working for some basic remaps, however, I haven't been able to remap the JSON values, or even confirm whether that is possible.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

## This is for the Node.JS integration of Granfana

To filter an array, you can use `array.filter`.

For example, if you have an array like so

```js
var names = [
   { "name":"program" },
   { "name":"application"}
]
```

You can filter my the name like so

```
var filtered = name.filter(n => n.name == "program")
// filtered = [{"name":"program"}]
```

Here is a full example:

```js
var logs = [
  {
    "labels": {
      "configuration_name":"serviceA",
      "location":"region",
      "service_name":"serviceA"
    },
    "type":""
   },
     {
    "labels": {
      "configuration_name":"programB",
      "location":"region",
      "service_name":"programB"
    },
    "type":""
   },
     {
    "labels": {
      "configuration_name":"systemC",
      "location":"region",
      "service_name":"systemC"
    },
    "type":""
   }
]

var filteredLogs = logs.filter(l => l.labels.configuration_name == "systemC")

console.log(filteredLogs[0])
```